# Get the attr of a dynamically created select child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created select element.  How would I be able to get the attr of the specific option chosen.  Right now it just gives me the att of the first element.

Here is my code

```
    $('button').click(function(){
        var arena = $(this).attr('id');
        var id = arena + '.jpg';
        $('#header').css('background-image', 'url('+id+')');
        $('#chooseArena').html("" + "<h1>Pick your ninja</h1>\
            <select name='first'>\
                <option id = 'black' value='black.png'>Black</option>\
                <option id = 'green' value='green.png'>Green</option>\
            <select>\
            <select name='second'>\
                <option value='black.png'>Black</option>\
                <option value='green.png'>Green</option>\
            <select>");

    });
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function(e){
        var ninja1 = $(e.target).children().attr('id'); //this always returns the first attr.  What should I do to get this to return the child element selected.
        alert(ninja1);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think option can have id attributes. Could you use var ninja1 = $(e.target).children().val(); instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the selected option within the context using [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(e){
    var ninja1 = $('option:selected', this).attr('id'); //this always returns the first attr.  What should I do to get this to return the child element selected.
    alert(ninja1);
});
```